# How to break chain in promise

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to limit the number of apis fetches in my project by saving them in a simple cache, key collection in mongodb. Is thera way to stop propagation of .then() inside Promise, without using async/await?

```
export const getData = (url: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        findInCache(url)
            .then((cached: string | null) => {
                if (cached) {
                    resolve(cached);
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        setCache(url, data, TTL);
                        resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(e => reject(e));
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: having `.then` inside Promise executor suggests you are guilty of the promise Constructor Anti-Pattern

Comment: @Liam Wound't calling reject result in triggering .catch in place where i call getData() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, lets get rid of the Promise constructor anti-pattern - your function call inside the promise executor returns a promise, so, no need for anew Promise

Secondly, only run the second request if the result of the first is empty

```
export const getData = (url) => findInCache(url)
// here we return haveResult and avoid axios.get(url) altogether
.then((haveResult) => haveResult || axios.get(url)
    // sometimes nested .then is useful like in this case
    .then(({data}) => {
        setCache(url, data, TTL);
        return data;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return something result in `then`, this result is come into next `then` function. So, you can control what you would do in next `then` based on input parameter `inCache`. So you can do something like:

```
export const getData = (url: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        findInCache(url)
            .then((cached: string | null) => {
                if (cached) {
                    resolve(cached);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .then((inCache) => {
                if (!inCache) {
                  axios
                      .get(url)
                      .then(({data}) => {
                          setCache(url, data, TTL);
                          resolve(data);
                      })
                      .catch(e => reject(e));
               }
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: This needs more explanation

Comment: Add **Update** in the answer

Comment: having `.then` inside Promise executor suggests you are guilty of the promise Constructor Anti-Pattern

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this instead instead of chaining. if it is in cache then fetch from cache else get from url

```
export const getData = (url: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        findInCache(url)
            .then((cached: string | null) => {
                if (cached) {
                    resolve(cached);
                } else {
                  axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        setCache(url, data, TTL);
                        resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(e => reject(e));
                  }
            })

    });
};
```

Comment: This needs more explanation

Comment: having `.then` inside Promise executor suggests you are guilty of the promise Constructor Anti-Pattern

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having too much of indenting in code. :/ I initially thought that calling resolve() would terminate rest of the code inside of a promise.